# Ethereum Wallet not mining

Tags: mining, ethminer

I installed latest Ethereum Wallent and I connected on test network and  I clicked on Start Mining (Testnet only), but nothing is happening. I still have 0 ETH in my account.

I'm not sure if it's bad a design or a bug, I have no idea if it works.

Also I've tried via console
1. `geth console`
2. in new console `geth attach`
3. miner.start(2)

I get this error

```
Error: etherbase missing: etherbase address must be explicitly specified
at web3.js:3104:20
at web3.js:6191:15
at web3.js:5004:36
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Not sure how to start miner to get some test ETHs

Comment: Please mention the testnet you are using. The complexity of mining varies by testnet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have at least one account, so that the client knows where to send the mined ETH. You can make a new account with `personal.newAccount("mypassword123")`. Then check that the account is set with `eth.coinbase`

Answer (score 1):

From the console,

1. You have to create an account first by :

   `personal.newAccount("password")`
2. If you already had it, then skip 1 and select your account by this command:

   `miner.setEtherbase(personal.listAccounts[0])`
3. Mine

   `miner.start(2)`